# How do I get TimeMachine to backup a FUSE filesystem?

Tags: macos, time-machine, backup, filesystem

I have -

```
/Users/me/Documents/
/Users/me/Documents/ADocument
...
/Users/me/Fuse4XFileSystem/
/Users/me/Fuse4XFileSystem/AnotherDocument
...
```

TimeMachine will happily backup `/Users/me/Documents` and everything beneath it. `/Users/me/Fuse4XFileSystem/` can be opened and navigated from the Finder or Terminal. TimeMachine however ignores `/Users/me/Fuse4XFileSystem/` when creating a backup.

How do I get TimeMachine to backup `/Users/me/Fuse4XFileSystem` ?

Comment: Have you tried mounting the FUSE filesystem to `/Volumes/Fuse4XFileSystem` and symlinking it to `/Users/me/Fuse4XFileSystem`? I had a similar issue with an external hard drive that I mounted directly to `/Users/Shared/Music` and didn't get backed up. Time Machine ignored it until I mounted it to `/Volumes/HDD`.